# C++ "std::string has not been declared" error

Tags: c++, string

I've been looking for an answer on websites but couldn't find any answer that helped me.

I have a code that uses strings when i tried (like suggested) to add these lines:

```
using namespace std;
using std::string;
#include <string>
```

I tried to use each of them separately and I tried all of them together. The best situation was when all of the string errors disappeared but I had another weird error on the line "using std::string" and the error was: std::string has not been declared.
Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: Why you vote that down? it's a beginner's question but a valid one.

Comment: @Roee I don't think it's useful for anyone, and any basic treatment of the language will cover this. I should probably link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list now.

Comment: You need to read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: where do they suggest these? any URL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put `#include <string>` first.

Avoid `using` statements in headers as you potentially bring in all sorts of stuff into many compilation units. `using std::string` is perhaps acceptable in a header but `using namespace std` **certainly isn't** as it will cause so much namespace pollution in all compilation units. The std namespace is continuously expanding (look at all the new stuff in C++), so you don't want to have to fix lots of errors when upgrading your compiler.

Comment: I don't think `using std::string` is acceptable in a header, *unless* it is in a limited scope.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel I know. But this answer explicitly speaks about headers.

Comment: @juanchopanza; I agree with you (it's one of the standards I enforce).

Comment: Some possibly helpful terminology: `using namespace std;` is a using directive. `using std::string;` is a using declaration.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I use it along with vector and plenty other using declarations in the common header that is forced include for all projects. With the best results. Using std:: on exotic stuff is tolerable, but otherwise is is just utter noise. Do you allow reusing name 'string' for other purposes?

Comment: @BalogPal I wouldn't allow to re-use `string` or `vector` or many other names, but people do it anyway. The number of times I've seen things called `list`, `map` or `set`...

Comment: so don't let people do it anyway... how hard it is to spot on a review really?

Answer (score 1):

The `include` should come before the `using`

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//using std::string; <-- Needless
```

Comment: Why encourage someone to say `using namsepace std`?

Comment: @juanchopanza (a) because it's a valid supported possibility. (b) I use it when I know what I'm doing and it never cause me any problem in the last 8 years...

Comment: Every day there is some SO post where someone has a problem that comes from `using namespace std`.

Comment: @juanchopanza what's the alternative?

Comment: @juanchopanza Every day there are car accidents, so you would advice people to stop driving anymore?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer you can refer to the string as `std::string` when required, or say `using std::string` in a limited scope, for example in a function or a class.

Comment: If I could see that some of these accidents are causeb by people driving blindfolded, I would at least make sure I don't suggest to learners to drive blindfolded.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You mean without adding the //so sue me comment a'la Scott Meyers? ;-)  The recent popular guideline is still like "not in header, fair game in .cpp file"

Comment: @BalogPal I wouldn't consider it fair game in a cpp file, unless it is in a limited scope. Of course, if it is only you who is maintaining the .cpp, then you can do whatever you like.

Comment: @juanchopanza: it's your fair choice. I just made a note that the alternative is also popular and accepted by top mentors

Comment: see now that i have encouraged a teaching discussion this post deserves a higher vote ;)

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer And indeed it has ;-)