# Expression for file operations using overloaded operators does not give expected results?

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to overload operators '+' and '=' for a customized class operating over files.
The  operator '+' overload appends the content of right operand file to left operand file.
And operator '=' overload writes the contents of right operand file into left operand file.
The operator overloads work fine independently but when combined in an expression they do not give expected results.
With the expression in below program efile3 = (efile2+efile1) results in efile3 getting contents of only efile2's contents prior to appending.
The efile2 is properly appended with efile1's content.
Why the expression fails to give expected results? Does it have something to do with operator precedence?

```
     #include<fstream>
     #include<string>
    class EasyFile{
        std::string fileContent;
        std::string temp1,temp;
        char* filePath;
        public:
            EasyFile(char* filePath){
               this->filePath = filePath;
               std::ifstream file(filePath);
               int count=0;
               while(file){
                   getline(file,temp1);
                   count++;
               }
               count--;
               std::ifstream file1(filePath);
               while(count!=0){
                    getline(file1,temp1);
                    temp = temp + temp1+"\n";
                    count--;
               }
               setFileContent(temp);
            }

            void setFileContent(std::string line){
                fileContent = line;

            }

            char* getFilePath(){
                return filePath;
            }

            std::string getFileContent(){
                return fileContent;
            }

            void setContent(std::string content){
                std::ofstream file(filePath);
                file<<content;
            }
            void operator=(EasyFile f);
            EasyFile operator+(EasyFile f);
    };
    void EasyFile::operator=(EasyFile f){
        this->setContent(f.getFileContent());
    }
    EasyFile EasyFile::operator+(EasyFile f){
        EasyFile f1(this->getFilePath());
        std::string totalContent = f1.getFileContent()+f.getFileContent();
        f1.setContent(totalContent);
        return f1;
    }

    int main(int argc,char** argv)
    {
        EasyFile efile1(argv[1]);
        EasyFile efile2(argv[2]);
        EasyFile efile3(argv[3]);
        efile3 =(efile2+efile1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If someone elaborates over that down vote i will happily delete the question! Thank you!

Comment: Your code is both incomplete and contains too much irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @melpomene Neglect the irrelevant stuff. But incomplete? Both the operators behave fine independently. Just the expression fails.

Comment: It's incomplete because it doesn't compile.

Comment: @melpomene and what is the compiler error you are getting? Because your comment questions my integrity.

Comment: The example [does compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7d28aee215a2411)

Comment: @Deepeshkumar `try.cc:2:14: error: ‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type` `std::string fileContent;` is the first one.

Comment: @melpomene See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040098/c-stdstring-has-not-been-declared-error  .It has to do with the compiler you are using. string class is now part of namespace 'std'.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar See this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17040165/1848654 Your code is missing `#include <string>`

Comment: How about `#include`ing  `<string>` and `<fstream>` ? :)

Comment: @melpomene I did not include those lines because i thought that it is obvious for a programmer to know that i have included them while compiling at my side.

Comment: OK, next piece of missing information: How are you running the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think that you're not flushing the data to `efile1`, that's why `efile3` gets only the "old" content.</strike>

**EDIT**: You should update your `fileContent` when setting the content:

Try this:

<kbd>[**Run It Online !**](http://goo.gl/5DfyFo)</kbd>

```
// this method is called by `operator+()`
void setContent(std::string content){
    std::ofstream file(filePath);
    file << content;
    setFileContent(content);  // this should update `fileContent`
                              // which is read by `operator=()`
                              // when it calls `setContent(f.getFileContent())`
                              // thus actually updating the left-hand side of the operation
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That resolved the issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You can even play with the code online if you want (check out the "Run It Online" button).

Comment: Thank you! Did not know this!